# How to import jquery typings to typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, typescript-typings

I realize that there are multiple question about this, but I'm having issues finding one that matches mine, maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

In my Visual Studio project I have used package.json to download jquery typings into the node_modules folder:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@syncfusion/ej2": "17.1.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-base": "17.1.49",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-data": "17.1.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-inputs": "17.1.50",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-buttons": "17.1.50",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-splitbuttons": "17.1.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-lists": "17.1.47",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-navigations": "17.1.49",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-popups": "17.1.50",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-charts": "17.1.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-calendars": "17.1.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-grids": "17.1.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-maps": "17.1.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-pdf-export": "17.1.48",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-svg-base": "17.1.48",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-file-utils": "17.1.47",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-compression": "17.1.47",
    "@types/jquery": "3.2.0"
  }
}
```

The actual project already uses jquery 2.1.4, but I'm thinking it shouldn't be too much of an issue if I got 3.2.0 as there wasn't a 2.1.4 available, is the types version was related to jquery script version?

My tsconfig.json has the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@syncfusion/ej2-base": [ "./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/dist/ej2-base.umd.min.js" ],
      "@syncfusion/ej2-buttons": [ "./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-buttons/dist/ej2-buttons.umd.min.js" ],
      "@syncfusion/ej2-popups": [ "./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-popups/dist/ej2-popups.umd.min.js" ],
      "@syncfusion/ej2-maps": [ "./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-maps/dist/ej2-maps.umd.min.js" ],
      "@types/jquery": [ "./node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts" ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

My page QBMapByState.aspx has the following javascript file QBMapByState.config.js:

```
System.config({
paths: {
'npm:': './node_modules/',
'syncfusion:': '../node_modules/@syncfusion/',
'types:': '../node_modules/@types/'

},
map: {
app: '../scripts/QBMapping',

//Syncfusion packages mapping
"@syncfusion/ej2-base": "syncfusion:ej2-base/dist/ej2-base.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-data": "syncfusion:ej2-data/dist/ej2-data.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-inputs": "syncfusion:ej2-inputs/dist/ej2-inputs.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-buttons": "syncfusion:ej2-buttons/dist/ej2-buttons.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-splitbuttons": "syncfusion:ej2-splitbuttons/dist/ej2-splitbuttons.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-lists": "syncfusion:ej2-lists/dist/ej2-lists.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-navigations": "syncfusion:ej2-navigations/dist/ej2-navigations.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-popups": "syncfusion:ej2-popups/dist/ej2-popups.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-charts": "syncfusion:ej2-charts/dist/ej2-charts.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-calendars": "syncfusion:ej2-calendars/dist/ej2-calendars.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-grids": "syncfusion:ej2-grids/dist/ej2-grids.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-maps": "syncfusion:ej2-maps/dist/ej2-maps.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-pdf-export": "syncfusion:ej2-pdf-export/dist/ej2-pdf-export.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-svg-base": "syncfusion:ej2-svg-base/dist/ej2-svg-base.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-file-utils": "syncfusion:ej2-file-utils/dist/ej2-file-utils.umd.min.js",
"@syncfusion/ej2-compression": "syncfusion:ej2-compression/dist/ej2-compression.umd.min.js"
},
packages: {
'app': { main: 'QBMapByState.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
}
});

System.import('app');
```

I'm not sure if I need to add anything in here in regards to the type jquery.

And in my page's typescript file QBMapByState.ts I do some imports including the jquery typing like so:

```
import { Maps } from "@syncfusion/ej2-maps";
import { RadioButton, CheckBox, Button, ChangeEventArgs } from '@syncfusion/ej2-buttons';
import * as $ from '@types/jquery';
```

All but the jquery is transpiling. I get the following error:

> Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'jquery'
>   instead of '@types/jquery'

How can I get this to work? Where am I going wrong?

Debug Errors:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you shouldn't import `$` from the jquery typings, you import it from jquery itself:

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

As for your other question, there are some [breaking changes](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/) between jquery 3 and jquery 2, so I'd imagine you want to use the type definitions for your jquery 2 installation:

```
npm install @types/jquery@2
```

Comment: thanks G1N now I'm getting 'Module "jquery" has no default export'

Comment: @Hank try `import * as $ from 'jquery'`;

Comment: Changed the package.json to get 2.0.53 as that was the largest version number and used import * as $ from 'jquery'. Now I get: Cannot find module 'jquery'

Comment: Did you install `jquery` using npm?

Comment: No I hadn't, missed that, I have removed jquery typing from node_modules, then ran the npm install, able to do a compile which is great! Where did it place the typing file then?

Comment: Just going to try pindev's way as well, to uninstall do I run: npm uninstall @types/jquery@2

Comment: you can uninstall using `npm uninstall @types/jquery`!

Comment: Hi G1N, come back to your solution as pindev's not responding and I need to continue. I've loaded the page and in the debugging console it outputs a couple of errors, I've placed a screenshot at the end of the question, any ideas

Comment: Did I need to add anything to tsconfig or QBMapByState.config.js?

Comment: How is jquery currently being loaded in your app? Do you use a script tag somewhere in an HTML file or have you installed it via npm? Are jquery functions working despite the errors?

Comment: Hi G1N, yes script tag on the asp.net master page, it works if I do an ajax call to a WebMethod on code-behind from content page. It is loaded via BundleConfig.cs, The site is a hybrid mixture of master/content pages and MVC, so it is a bit messy, pretty sure the jquery-2.1.4.min.js was just copied into place, so I don't think npm was used, it is an existing project I'm adding functionality to.

Comment: could you install jquery via npm (`npm install jquery@2.1.4`) and see if the problem persists? When you import from `jquery` in typescript it'll look for the jquery files in your node_modules folder. I'm not sure if having it installed both via npm and with the inline jquery script will cause problems

Answer (score 1):

You should add `typeRoots` to the `tsconfig.json`.

You can check it here how to use it.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

Comment: Ok, so I can do this with node_modules or as in G1N's example with NPM, the choice is mine?

Comment: Yes, you can use any one you want. :)

Comment: I have added back "@types/jquery": "2.0.53" in package.json and added "types": [ "jquery" ] into tsconfig.json. I have removed the path that was originally in "paths" in tsconfig, do I add that back? And have kept: "import * as $ from 'jquery';" in the ts file.

Comment: error occuring under 'jquery' in ts file: Error TS2497(TS) Module jquery resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.

Comment: pindev you still around?